# Python: My program is not executing a for loop properly

Tags: python

I have a list, `num_list`, which contains random numbers identified by using random.
One for loop is responsible for selecting numbers from the original list and my compare function is supposed to compare the obtained number with the numbers present in my new list. If the number is greater than the first number obtained from the for loop, I check if the same num is less than the next num in the new list. This means that the num is between the numbers and is therefore inserted there. However, I am stuck in a loop and can't understand what is going on. I have tried everything I know but, sadly, I'm still just a beginner. I hope someone here can make head or tail of this unfortunate mess.

```
new_list.append((num_list)[0])

def compare(num, new_list, index, temp_char):
    for char in new_list:
        print(char)
        if num > char:
            index = new_list.index(char)
            try:
                temp_char = (new_list)[index + 1]
                if num <= temp_char:
                    new_list.insert(index+1, num)
            except:
                new_list.insert(index, num)

        break

for num in num_list:
    #print(num)
    compare(num, new_list, index, temp_char)
print(new_list)
```

Comment: please include the code in which you generate the `num_list`

Comment: please share a sample `num_list`

Comment: You shouldn't modify the list as you're iterating over it

Comment: @Sayse he's not, he's editing `new_list` while iterating over `num_list`

Comment: @Sayse whoops, you are right.

Comment: for i in range (10):
    temp_num = random.randint(0, 50)
    num_list.append(temp_num)                                                                      
                                                output:[38, 21, 28, 31, 42, 9, 18, 28, 47, 38]

Answer (score 0):

As Sayse said in comment, you shouldn't modify a list while iterating over it. This leads to undefined behavior. Instead, copy the list new_list before iterating over it. To copy the list, there are many solutions, but here's a simple one: `copied = [i for i in new_list]`

This won't work if your list is a nested list.